# Parse variables in column separated by non-alphabetic characters

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a column that contains variables that are separated either by a '/' or a '-'. 
an example of a cell would look like this :

```
|Column 1|
|x-a/b-x-a|
```

Using R, I want to only keep the first instance of a variable. The output would look like this:

```
|Column1|
|x-a/b|
```

I require the first instance of a variable because the '/' and '-' signify different things. Also if it makes it at all easier in a particular cell there can only be one instance of a variable. So only 1 x, a, and b, in the above example.

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you. 
Here is code to create a reproducible example:

```
data_frame(x = c(('x-a/b-x-a'),('d/w-a-a-a'), ('b-c/d-b-c/d')))
```

and here is code to create what I would like the output to look like :

```
data_frame(x = c(('x-a/b'),('d/w-a'), ('b-c/d')))
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: NB the data frame constructor function is ````data.frame````, not ````data_frame````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will do exactly what you want using a regular expression, but it will only work assuming what you want is the first set of three letters separated by either / or -. Any deviation from that will break this particular solution, but you can play around with the regular expression to fit other cases.

I took the liberty of adding a second vector to illustrate how to process a data.frame with multiple columns.

```
d <- data.frame( x = c ( ( 'x-a/b-x-a' ), ( 'd/w-a-a-a' ), ( 'b-c/d-b-c/d' ) ), y = c ( ( 'x-a/b-x-a' ), ( 'd/w-a-a-a' ), ( 'b-c/d-b-c/d' ) ) )
out <- as.data.frame(
    lapply( d, function( v ) {
        sub( "([a-z][-/][a-z][-/][a-z]).*", "\\1", v )
    } ) 
)
out
      x     y
1 x-a/b x-a/b
2 d/w-a d/w-a
3 b-c/d b-c/d
```

The same function arrangement (`sub` inside `lapply`) may be used for other transformations using a different regular expression, like `[a-z]+[/-][a-z]+[/-][a-z]+`, etc.

If you want a cleaner syntax, you can also obtain the same result without lapply using dplyr and magrittr's pipe operator:

```
require( magrittr )
require( dplyr )
out <- d %>% mutate(
    x = sub( "([a-z][-/][a-z][-/][a-z]).*", "\\1", x ),
    y = sub( "([a-z][-/][a-z][-/][a-z]).*", "\\1", y )
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. If I want more than just three letters do I just add another [-/][a-z] just before the .*?

Comment: Yes, that is one way of doing it, but it has the limitation that it needs you to specify each element by hand (however symbolically). Regular expressions also support groups and quantifiers, but they (1) get tricky, because you want a-b-c, not -a-b-c, etc and (2) seem out of scope for this questions :)

Comment: So I tried this on my actual data. Does this only work for letters? My actual data the variables are drug ingredient names. How would I tweak it to work with my data? Also is it possible for this to return the entire data frame that I am applying the code to. Right now this will return only the one column that I parse.

Comment: As I said in the answer, this will _only_ work for your specific request, one letter, one separator that is either / or -, because the regular expression is coded like that: ````[a-z]```` means "one and only one lowercase letter in the a-z range", and ````[/-]```` means "one and only one of either \ or -". But the general idea holds: you can use those functions with other regular expressions. E.g. if your drug names are always only lowercase letters, this expression should work: ````[a-z]+[/-][a-z]+[/-][a-z]+````, because ````[a-z]+```` means "one or more lowercase letters in the a-z range".

Comment: My drug names are all lowercase  but I still get duplicates. for example: prednisone-prednisone

Comment: I would need to see your input data to figure out what's wrong, but as i said above, that starts to drift into regular expressions territory, and that is a vast, vast topic.

Comment: Alright I will play around with it and see if I can get it to give me what I want. Thank you for you help.